# Functions Proof

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

2. Consider the function f : N → N defined, for every n ∈ N, by 
   "f(n) = (n + 1)! − 1"

1.Prove that, for every n ∈ N, f(n + 1) > f(n)

2.Prove that f is injective.

Can somebody shed some light on these? Ive been struggling with this for the past few days

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for any (arbitrary) $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\begin{align}
f(n+1) &= (n+2)! -1 = (n+2)(n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2)\left((n+1)!-1\right) + (n+2) - 1 \\
&= (n+2) \cdot f(n) + (n+1)
\end{align}$$

For the second part, observe that a function which is strictly increasing is in particular injective.

Comment: How did you get the Second line? I didn't understand where you got (n+2) - 1 from?

Comment: By rewriting the equation, adding and substracting the same term: $$ab - 1 = ab -a + a -1 = a(b-1)+a-1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n+1)=\underbrace{(n+2)!}_{>(n+1)!}-1<(n+1)!-1=f(n)$$

If $n\neq m$ then $(n+1)!\neq (m+1)!$ and so $(n+1)!-1\neq (m+1)!-1$ therefore $f(n)\neq f(m)$ thus $f$ is injective.

Comment: Check the inequality sign.

Answer (score -3):

To show injective we show that if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$.

So $f(x) = (x+1)!-1 = (y+1)!-1 = f(y)$ so it is injective.

Comment: Is that all that needs to be done for the question? Because it says Prove for every do you not need to show for n+1 or n+2?

Comment: Yes, that's all, because I made no assumptions on $x$ (should have used $n$).

Comment: No, that's backwards. Injectivity is "if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x = y$".

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: There very much _is_ a difference. For _any_ function $f$, if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y).$ But only injective functions have the converse of that.